# I need access to variables both in php and the page's javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a php/JavaScript web application that must perform many calculations using many values input by the user.  There are several pages of inputs, and calculations using values input on previous pages are everywhere.

I have been passing the recently entered values between pages using `$_POST`, and storing them for use in a serialized class saved as a `$_SESSION` variable.  One obvious way to pass values from PHP to the page for use by JavaScript is to populate the page with hidden form elements.  JavaScript could use this data and modify it as necessary, then pass the values via `POST`.

I may have many such hidden elements, and I can't help but think that this is a good way to slow down the pages.  Is there a better way to store this data between pages?  Cookies?

Thanks!
SH

Comment: This is the perfect example for AJAX (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX). This allows you to separate presentation and data. Your page can load with just the presentation, and immediately request data without having to (re)load any pages - only data is transferred. You then use data to populate your page. In addition, you can use AJAX to save the data without having to submit the page and load something. If you use any libraries/frameworks, there's usually a helper function or concept of AJAX. Think jQuery/Angular.js

Comment: Have you considered writing the whole application in JavaScript on a single page and only posting to the server the data you need it to store?

Comment: @Ian - If I understand you correctly, you're saying that I would load the page, then use AJAX and JS to populate the fields.  For the values that are entered on other pages, but that might not be displayed on this page, would I just use AJAX to call them from the session variable when needed?  Is that how you see this?

Comment: @Hobo - That was a consideration, but it would be a very long page.

Answer (score 0):

Search AJAX in google. It's a technic that helps your javascript to communicate with your php. First it is hard to learn the syntax but watching videos from youtube will do just fine.